# Python - beautifulsoup, apply in every text file in folder and produce new text file

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup

I am using the following Python - Beautifulsoup code to remove html elements from a text file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("textFileWithHtml.txt") as markup:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())

with open("strip_textFileWithHtml.txt", "w") as f: 
    f.write(soup.get_text().encode('utf-8'))
```

The question I have is how can I apply this code to every text file in a folder(directory), and for each text file produce a new text file which is processed and where the html elements etc. are removed, without having to call the function for each and every text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave that work to the OS, simply replace the hardcoded input file with input from external source, in `argv` array, and invoke the script inside a loop or with a regular expression that matches many files, like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

for fi in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(fi) as markup:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())

    with open("strip_" + fi, "w") as f: 
        f.write(soup.get_text().encode('utf-8'))
```

And run it like:

```
python script.py *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working. If the .txt files are not in the same folders, would something like python script.py 'path-to-folder/*.txt' work?

Comment: Not now, because the prefix would be inserted at the beginning of the full path. You can solve it appending it at the end, like `with open(fi + "_strip", "w") as f:`. The alternative is to handle it inside the script, doing a partition of the path from the file, add the prefix and join it again. There is a standard `python` module to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

The [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/glob.html) module lets you list all the files in a directory:

```
import glob
for path in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(path) as markup:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())

    with open("strip_" + path, "w") as f: 
        f.write(soup.get_text().encode('utf-8'))
```

If you want to also do that for every subfolder recursively, check out [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.walk)