# sed command - apply in all text (.txt) files of folder

Tags: bash, sed

I want to apply this sed command

```
sed '/begin 644/,$d' file1.txt > file1.txt
```

to all files of the directory.. basically I want to keep the having the same name but deleting all lines after a certain string is found.. how can i adjust this sed command to be applied to all the text (.txt) files in the folder and keep their original names ?

EDIT : I am using Mac OS X I don't know if there is some issue with the sed command...

if i try to do

```
sed -i '/begin 644/,$d' *.txt
```

i get an error sed: 1: bad flag in substitute command : 'x'

2nd EDIT : Anu's answer works !

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-the-file-in-place

Comment: Haha thanks man but is it somehow special ? :D I was waiting for it tho :D

Comment: I don't know, I've forgotten at which levels you get extra abilities on SO.  Unless your pages are now showing alerts at the top, I guess the answer is 'no'.  ;)

Comment: A "review" button appeared in the top and here  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges it says i can review posts whatever that means :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `find` with `sed`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i.bak '/begin 644/,$d' {} +
```

Or if you want to keep `begin 644`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i.bak -n '1,/begin 644/p' {} +
```

Comment: hi anu. i want to delete the lines AFTER the match is found.. for example, if begin 644 is written in line 100, i want to delete all lines from 100 till the end.. i think you need to change your regex

Comment: `sed -n '1,/begin 644/p' file` actually does same but I will change it your sed command.

Comment: it is not working, it is creating a .bak file which is the original file and then a file without the .bak name which is empty.. EDIT : I am using Mac OS X maybe there is some issue with the sed command ?

Comment: This is to cater OSX ( I am also using OSX). Try: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i.bak '/begin 644/,$d' {} \;`

Comment: now it creates 2 files which are the same as the original.. one example of a line after which I want to delete: begin 644 g274705g08j38.jpg . Maybe there is some issue with the regex or else why is not deleting the lines after the match?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71292/discussion-between-anubhava-and-adrcoder).

Comment: hey anu i am trying ur code but if there are many files in the folder only one is processed and the others are empty (zero bytes).. do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i.bak '/begin 644/,$d' {} \;` should run on all matching `*.txt` files

Comment: even if the folder has only 2 files, it only processed 1, the other the .txt file is empty and a .bak is created which has the contents of the original .txt file..

Comment: Sorry, sorry, the command you just wrote in the comments works . Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Just use in-place version of `sed` as

```
sed -i '/begin 644/,$d' file1.txt
```

Comment: On MacOsX you will have to use 'sed -i.random-file-extension', because their version of sed is ancient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the edit in place sed option and the star selector like so

```
sed -i '/begin 644/,$d' *.txt
```